# Any Tool/Trick to delete common files between 2 folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd, directory

I have 2 folder which contents are almost identical, what I wish to do is to find the files that does not exist to each of them

`Folder 1: a.doc, b.doc, c.doc, d.doc`
`Folder 2: b.doc, d.doc, e.doc`

Since, each folder has both `b.doc, d.doc` the output becomes:

`Folder 1: a.doc, c.doc`
`Folder 2: e.doc`

*(yes, it automatically deletes it)*

Each folder contains 1000+ files whose file name are all korean.

What I'm currently doing is via command prompt I get the list of file names through dir, but actually it is nothing but just manual.

Please can somebody help?

Comment: Are all the files in singular folders? or does each folder contain sub folders?

Comment: @scunliffe singular folder only.

Comment: I think @foxidrive has the easiest answer... but if you were going to do code something more generic I'd probably do something like this (pseudo code): http://pastebin.com/JyPd22sh

Comment: @scunliffe I wanna try PHP since I believe it can handle other encoding, but the problem is that some files have so many characters in its file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work without having to handle the korean file names.

**warning** This code DELETES all common files between folders A and B taking in consideration only the filename.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Target folders configuration
    set "folderA=%cd%\a"
    set "folderB=%cd%\b"

    rem -----------------------------------------------------

    rem Temporary work folders and output options
    set "folderA1=%temp%\%~n0.a.%random%%random%%random%.tmp"
    set "folderB1=%temp%\%~n0.b.%random%%random%%random%.tmp"
    set "rcOpt=/njh /njs /np /nfl /ndl > nul"

    rem Create a duplicate of the folders, with 0 bytes files 
    robocopy "%folderA%" "%folderA1%" /create %rcOpt%
    robocopy "%folderB%" "%folderB1%" /create %rcOpt%

    rem Remove all files in B1 present in A
    rem Overwrites the files in A that will later be removed
    robocopy "%folderB1%" "%folderA%" /xl /mov %rcOpt%

    rem Remove all files in A1 present in B
    rem Overwrites the files in B that will later be removed
    robocopy "%folderA1%" "%folderB%" /xl /mov %rcOpt%

    rem A1 contains only the non common files in A
    rem B1 contains only the non common files in B

    rem Delete from target folders the files not present in source 
    robocopy "%folderA1%" "%folderA%" /nocopy /purge %rcOpt%
    robocopy "%folderB1%" "%folderB%" /nocopy /purge %rcOpt%

    rem Cleanup
    rmdir /s /q "%folderA1%" >nul 2>nul
    rmdir /s /q "%folderB1%" >nul 2>nul
```

Comment: Sorry, should this bat file be, say in  "C:\file.bat" and the folders: "C:\a" & "C:\b" ?

Thanks!

Comment: @TheWolf, place the batch file in any place OUT of the involved folders and change the `set "folderA=..."` and `set "folderB=..."` to the full path to the two folders to process. The definition in sample code reflects my test environment with two subfolders from current directory.

Comment: thank you. seems like that's the only thing I need to change right?

Comment: @TheWolf, yes. They define your environment. The rest of requirements in the script (the `%temp%` folder and the existence of `robocopy`) are standard in a windows 7 environment.

Answer (score 2):

This should create `"c:\file.bat.txt"` for you to `examine for accuracy` in notepad before renaming it to a `bat` and executing it.

A problem may be the `Korean filenames`, as non-english and unicode characters aren't always handled well by batch files.  Changing the code page may be needed.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("c:\folder1\*.*") do if exist "c:\folder2\%%~nxa"  >"c:\file.bat.txt" echo del "%%a"
for %%a in ("c:\folder2\*.*") do if exist "c:\folder1\%%~nxa" >>"c:\file.bat.txt" echo del "%%a"
pause
```